# Vector of int initialized with 0s on acces gives non zero value

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a simple algorithm to find odd cycles in a graph. I have a visited vector that tells me if a vector was visited, it is initialized with 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

#define UNVISITED 0
#define VISITED 1

using namespace std;

int vertices, edges;

vector<vector<int>> graph;
vector<int> visited;
vector<int> times;

int time_ = 1;
int hasOddCycle = false;

void dfs(int vertex) {
    if (visited.at(vertex) == VISITED)
        return;
    visited.at(vertex) = VISITED;
    times.at(vertex) = time_;
    time_++;

    for (auto elem: graph.at(vertex)) {
        if (visited.at(elem) == VISITED) {
            if (times.at(vertex) - times.at(elem) % 2 == 0)
                hasOddCycle = true;
        } else {
            dfs(elem);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cin >> vertices >> edges;

    for (int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++) {
        visited.emplace_back(UNVISITED);
        graph.emplace_back(vector<int>());
        times.push_back(0);
    }

    int from, to;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {
        cin >> from >> to;
        graph.at(from).push_back(to);
        graph.at(to).push_back(from);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= vertices; i++) {
        dfs(i);
        if (hasOddCycle) {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "YES" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run my code with given data dfs(1) is called and sets visited at 1 to 0. First element in a dfs loop is 2 so I check if vertex 2 was visited and it gives me true for no reason!!! I have no idea why that is...

The input data (vertices, edges counts and than vertices):

```
5 6
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
1 5
5 3
```

Comment: The best solution would be to run your program in debugger, analyze all data points and see when the behavior is not what you expected. Further reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I did and debugger shows that values in vector visited at 2 should be 0, but it is not

Comment: at what line does it become 2 instead of 0?

Comment: Then you can now check where the error came from.

Comment: It is in line `if (visited.at(elem) == VISITED)` elem has a value of 2 and visited.at(2) should have a value of 0 but it doesn't. It happens in the first dfs call.

Comment: Are you sure you handle well time_ ? It is the same global variable for all vertices.

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://ideone.com/FWSd3z.  As you can see in the output, `visited` is only set to 1 for a vertex after you visit that vertex.

Comment: @mikol The debugger is supposed to be used so that you can step one line at a time in your program, view the value of variables, check the flow of the program, and then you are supposed to determine where the program deviates from your expectations.  The debugger has no idea what your program is supposed to do -- you know what your program is supposed to do.  Just running the debugger and reporting back what you already know doesn't help.

Comment: @interjay You're correct. I removed my ramblings to not confuse anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your verification of visitations is off and the global `time_` variable makes it hard to follow. Since the `times` vector supply the same information as the `visited` vector *and* more, I've removed the `visited` one. Every time you call `dfs` from `main` the visited times count for every vertex in the graph will be increased by one. They will all have the same number of visitations when the function returns. Here's an alternative way of keeping track of the visitaions that makes it a little easier to follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std; // bad practice

int vertices, edges;

vector<vector<int>> graph;
vector<int> times;

void dfs(int vertex) {
    static int indent = 1; // to indent recursion level in debug print

    int time_ = ++times.at(vertex);

    for (auto elem : graph.at(vertex)) {
        if (times.at(elem) != time_) {
            std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << "dfs(" << elem
                      << ") in graph @ vertex " << vertex << "\n";
            ++indent;
            dfs(elem);
            --indent;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cin >> vertices >> edges;

    times.resize(vertices+1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++) {
        graph.emplace_back(vector<int>());
    }

    int from, to;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {
        cin >> from >> to;
        graph.at(from).push_back(to);
        graph.at(to).push_back(from);
    }

    for(int v=1; v<=vertices; ++v) {
    std::cout << "\nchecking graph from vertex " << v << "\n";
        dfs(v);
        for (int i = 1; i <= vertices; i++) {
            if (times[i] != v) {
                std::cout << " Error\n";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        std::cout << " all vertices has " << v << " visitation(s)\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
checking graph from vertex 1
 dfs(2) in graph @ vertex 1
  dfs(3) in graph @ vertex 2
   dfs(4) in graph @ vertex 3
   dfs(5) in graph @ vertex 3
 all vertices has 1 visitation(s)

checking graph from vertex 2
 dfs(1) in graph @ vertex 2
  dfs(4) in graph @ vertex 1
   dfs(3) in graph @ vertex 4
    dfs(5) in graph @ vertex 3
 all vertices has 2 visitation(s)

checking graph from vertex 3
 dfs(2) in graph @ vertex 3
  dfs(1) in graph @ vertex 2
   dfs(4) in graph @ vertex 1
   dfs(5) in graph @ vertex 1
 all vertices has 3 visitation(s)

checking graph from vertex 4
 dfs(3) in graph @ vertex 4
  dfs(2) in graph @ vertex 3
   dfs(1) in graph @ vertex 2
    dfs(5) in graph @ vertex 1
 all vertices has 4 visitation(s)

checking graph from vertex 5
 dfs(1) in graph @ vertex 5
  dfs(2) in graph @ vertex 1
   dfs(3) in graph @ vertex 2
    dfs(4) in graph @ vertex 3
 all vertices has 5 visitation(s)
```